# select where all rows having same foreign key, meet the condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `operation` and `operationTask`. let's say that `operation` only has

- ID

and `operationTask` has

- ID
- operation_id "as foreign key"
- status "Boolean 0:1"

The relation between these two tables is one-to-many.

I want to select all operations where all of their tasks "operationtask" status is equal to 1.

What I have tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `operation` 
WHERE operation.id = All(
    SELECT task.operation_id 
    FROM operationtask task 
    WHERE task.status=1 
    GROUP BY task.operation_id)
```

for example:

operation:

```
ID
---
1
2
3
```

operationtask:

```
ID   operation_id   status
---  ------------   ------
1         1           1
2         1           0
3         2           1
4         2           1
5         3           0
6         3           0
```

the result should be:

operation:

```
ID
---
2
```

Comment: What is the Problem with your code?

Comment: @Jens didn't return the right result

Comment: can you Show some sample data with expected result and result you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from operations o
where not exists (
      select 1 
      from operationtask t 
      where t.operation_id = o.id and t.status = 0)
```